# How can my Cocoa application be notified of NSScreen resolution changes?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, screen-resolution

I am making a Cocoa application with a floating window. The floating window is supposed to be centered on the main screen, at a size which is 1/4 of the main screen. The following Swift is the essence of my application:

```
import Cocoa
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var panel: NSPanel!
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let screenRect:CGRect = NSScreen.main()!.frame
        panel = NSPanel(
            contentRect: NSRect(
                x: screenRect.width/4,
                y: screenRect.height/4,
                width:  screenRect.width/2,
                height: screenRect.height/2
            ),
            styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask.nonactivatingPanel,
            backing: NSBackingStoreType.buffered,
            defer: false
        )
        panel.alphaValue = 0.5
        panel.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
        panel.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.maximumWindow))
        panel.orderFront(nil)
    }
}
```

This produces a panel like this:

[image: CORRECTLY POSITIONED]

The problem arises when the main screen resolution changes. One way to show this is to go to System Preferences > Displays and set the resolution to "Scaled" and "More Space". After doing so, the panel looks like this:

[image: INCORRECTLY POSITIONED AFTER RESOLUTION CHANGE]

As you can see, the position of the panel is incorrect after the resolution is changed. I wish for the panel to maintain its position: centered and 1/4 the size of the screen. To do so, I to detect when the screen resolution (i.e., the `frame` property of the `NSScreen`) changes, so that I can change the size and position of the panel.

Is there some event which is fired when the `frame` property of an `NSScreen` changes? Or is there a different way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of @Adolfo, this works:

```
import Cocoa
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var panel: NSPanel!

    func getPanelRect() -> NSRect {
        let screenRect:CGRect = NSScreen.main()!.frame
        return NSRect(
            x: screenRect.width/4,
            y: screenRect.height/4,
            width:  screenRect.width/2,
            height: screenRect.height/2
        )
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        panel = NSPanel(
            contentRect: self.getPanelRect(),
            styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask.nonactivatingPanel,
            backing: NSBackingStoreType.buffered,
            defer: false
        )
        panel.alphaValue = 0.5
        panel.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
        panel.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.maximumWindow))
        panel.orderFront(nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: NSNotification.Name.NSApplicationDidChangeScreenParameters,
            object: NSApplication.shared(),
            queue: OperationQueue.main
        ) { notification -> Void in
            print("screen parameters changed")
            self.panel.setFrame(self.getPanelRect(), display: true)
        }
    }
}
```